# Flexible array member replacement for constexpr context

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

I want an array of objects prefixed with size/capacity. My requirements are:

1. The array elements should to be constructed on demand, like `std::vector`.
2. This object itself will be shared (i.e., heap allocated), so using `std::vector` instead would imply 2 levels of indirection and 2 allocations, which I have to avoid.

Requirements up to this point are non-negotiable. Here's my sample to get the rough idea of what I'd do:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

template <class T>
struct Array {
   private:
    int size_;
    int capacity_;
    alignas(T) unsigned char data_[];

    Array() = default;

   public:
    Array(Array const&) = delete;
    Array& operator=(Array const&) = delete;

    static auto newArr(int capacity) {
        auto p = new unsigned char[sizeof(Array) + capacity * sizeof(T)];
        auto pObj = new (p) Array;
        pObj->size_ = 0;
        pObj->capacity_ = capacity;
        return pObj;
    }

    static auto deleteArr(Array* arr) {
        if (!arr) return;
        for (int i = 0; i != arr->size_; ++i) arr->get(i).~T();
        arr->~Array();
        delete[] reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(arr);
    }

    auto& get(int index) {
        return reinterpret_cast<T&>(data_[index * sizeof(T)]);
    }

    auto push_back(T const& t) {
        assert(size_ < capacity_);
        new (&get(size_++)) T(t);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto arr = Array<std::string>::newArr(5);
    for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i) {
        arr->push_back(std::to_string(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i) {
        std::printf("arr[%d] = %s\n", i, arr->get(i).c_str());
    }
    Array<std::string>::deleteArr(arr);
}
```

It uses a flexible-array-member, which is an extension and that's OK by me (works in GCC and clang? then it's OK). But it is not constexpr friendly because it necessarily uses:

1. placement new, not allowed in constexpr context for some reason, even though that's surely what allocators do. We can't replace it with an allocator because they don't support the flexible array member trick.
2. reinterpret_cast to access the elements as `T` and to free the memory at the end.

My question:
How do I satisfy the previously mentioned requirements and keep the class constexpr friendly?

Comment: `unsigned char data_[];` -- *But it is not constexpr friendly because it necessarily uses:* -- It isn't C++ -- there is no obligation for this to adhere to anything in modern C++.   Even some STL algorithm functions didn't work with them, instead giving weird compiler errors.  I suggest you use standard C++ for whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how would I do that in complaint C++ then? My sample is just a sample, I am aware that it's not perfect (hence the question). This object is not going to be copied, etc., at all so I don't care that STL algorithms that try to copy it fail, it's OK.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: "*how would I do that in complaint C++ then?*" I could answer that, but it wouldn't help because, while those tools are legal C++, they also aren't allowed in `constexpr` code.

Comment: @NicolBolas Please do show me how it can be done without the flexible array member extension despite the lack of constexpr.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: `Array` needs to be aligned to `alignof(T)`. The address of the first array element should therefore be `this + 1` when you're within `Array`. But that doesn't point at an actual `T` even if you `reinterpret_cast` it. So you need to do the cast then `std::launder` the pointer; that will give you a pointer to the first element of the array. But this is only valid if there is at least one `T` there, so you shouldn't do it if `size_` is zero.

Comment: @NicolBolas and how does that obviate the need for the flexible array member extension? Please write up an answer if you have the time, I will surely upvote it.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: The only purpose for the flexible member `data_` is that it is the pointer to the first member of the array following `Array`. My alternative is a different way of computing such a pointer, given a pointer to a suitably allocated `Array` object.

Comment: @NicolBolas like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oonxMhbvo)?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: The `reinterpret_cast` needs to happen before the `launder`. But otherwise, that looks about right.

Comment: @NicolBolas I wonder if `std::launder` will cause any pessimization down the road.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, what you're trying to do is create a contiguous series of objects in unformed memory that isn't defined by a single, valid C++ struct or by a C++ array of `T`s. Constexpr allocations cannot do that.

You can allocate a byte array in constexpr code. But you cannot subsequently do any of the casting that normal C++ would require in order to partition this memory into a series of objects of different types. You can allocate storage suitable for an array of `Array<T>` objects. Or you can allocate storage suitable for an array of `T` objects. But `std::allocator<T>::allocate` will always return a `T*`. And constexpr code doesn't let you cast this pointer to some other, unrelated type.

And without being able to do this cast, you cannot later call `std::construct_at<T>`, since the template parameter `T` must match the pointer type you give it.

This is of course by design. Every constexpr allocation of type `T` must contain zero or more `T`s. That's all it can contain.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. *Constexpr allocations cannot do that.* It's kind of a shame that this cannot be done in constexpr. I don't see why it should be the case, it has no runtime dependencies and can be done without causing UB in standard C++ as we discussed in the comments.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Because compile-time code needs to not open the Pandora's Box of `reinterpret_cast` even a crack. A pointer at compile time is not merely an address. Since the standard *requires* that implementations diagnose compile-time UB as ill-formed, a pointer needs to know what it really points to, what the "memory" really is. That's way easier to maintain when code is flat-out forbidden from casting the types of pointers to objects.

Comment: I did it, at the cost of an indirection, it does separate allocation when constant evaluated, which is fine, no perf concerns there, and does our single-allocation+reinterpret_cast trick if created at runtime. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6fKc6nbPW

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: You should probably post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Considering [@NicolBolas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71303103/10147399), this can't be done as is, but if you can afford an indirection, it can be done. You do separate allocations if the object is constructed at compile-time where performance concern doesn't exist, and do the single-allocation + reinterpret_cast trick if constructed at runtime:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <new>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
struct ArrayData {
   protected:
    int size_ = 0;
    int capacity_ = 0;
    T *buffer;
};

template <class T>
struct alignas(std::max(alignof(T), alignof(ArrayData<T>))) Array
    : ArrayData<T> {
   private:
    constexpr Array() = default;
    using alloc = std::allocator<T>;
    using alloc_traits = std::allocator_traits<alloc>;

   public:
    Array(Array const &) = delete;
    Array &operator=(Array const &) = delete;

    constexpr static auto newArr(int capacity) {
        if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
            auto arr = new Array<T>();
            alloc a;
            T *buffer = alloc_traits::allocate(a, capacity);
            arr->capacity_ = capacity;
            arr->buffer = buffer;
            return arr;
        } else {
            auto p = new unsigned char[sizeof(Array) + capacity * sizeof(T)];
            auto pObj = new (p) Array;
            pObj->capacity_ = capacity;
            pObj->buffer = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T *>(pObj + 1));
            return pObj;
        }
    }

    constexpr static auto deleteArr(Array *arr) noexcept {
        if (!arr) return;

        auto p = arr->buffer;
        for (int i = 0, size = arr->size_; i != size; ++i)
                std::destroy_at(p + i);

        if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
            auto capacity = arr->capacity_;
            delete arr;
            alloc a;
            alloc_traits::deallocate(a, p, capacity);
        } else {
            arr->~Array();
            delete[] reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(arr);
        }
    }

    constexpr auto &get(int index) { return this->buffer[index]; }

    constexpr auto push_back(T const &t) {
        assert(this->size_ < this->capacity_);
        std::construct_at(this->buffer + this->size_++, t);
    }
};

constexpr int test() {
    auto const size = 10;
    auto arr = Array<int>::newArr(size);

    for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i) arr->push_back(i);

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i) sum += arr->get(i);

    Array<int>::deleteArr(arr);
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int rt = test();
    int constexpr ct = test();
    return rt == ct;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach. I've used unions to make it possible for subobjects of a single array object to have different types and different lifetimes. I'm not entirely sure if everything's strictly legal, but the major compilers don't complain.

I did need to have `newArr` return an object rather than pointer. If that's not an issue, it would probably make more sense to just give `FlexArray` an actual constructor and destructor.

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
class FlexArray
{
public:
    FlexArray(const FlexArray&) = delete;
    FlexArray& operator=(const FlexArray&) = delete;

    static constexpr FlexArray newArr(unsigned int capacity);
    constexpr void deleteArr();
    constexpr unsigned int size() const;
    constexpr unsigned int capacity() const;
    constexpr T& get(unsigned int index);
    constexpr void push_back(T const& obj);

private:
    struct Header {
        unsigned int size;
        unsigned int capacity;
    };
    static constexpr auto T_per_node =
    (sizeof(T) < sizeof(Header)) ? sizeof(Header)/sizeof(T) : 1U;
    union MaybeT {
        unsigned char dummy;
        T obj;

        constexpr MaybeT() {}
        explicit constexpr MaybeT(const T& src) : obj(src) {}
        constexpr ~MaybeT() {}
    };
    union U {
        Header head;
        MaybeT data[T_per_node];
        constexpr U() : data{} {}
        constexpr ~U() {}
    };

    U* nodes;
    explicit constexpr FlexArray(U* n) : nodes(n) {}
};

template <typename T>
constexpr FlexArray<T> FlexArray<T>::newArr(unsigned int capacity)
{
    auto new_nodes = new U[1 + (capacity + (T_per_node-1))/T_per_node];
    new_nodes[0].head = {0, capacity};
    return FlexArray{new_nodes};
}

template <typename T>
constexpr void FlexArray<T>::deleteArr()
{
    unsigned int i = size();
    while (i--) {
        get(i).~T();
    }
    delete[] nodes;
    nodes = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr unsigned int FlexArray<T>::size() const
{
    return nodes[0].head.size;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr unsigned int FlexArray<T>::capacity() const
{
    return nodes[0].head.capacity;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr T& FlexArray<T>::get(unsigned int index)
{
    return nodes[1 + index / T_per_node].data[index % T_per_node].obj;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr void FlexArray<T>::push_back(const T& obj)
{
    assert(size() < capacity());
    auto index = nodes[0].head.size++;
    MaybeT *addr = nodes[1 + index / T_per_node].data + (index % T_per_node);
    addr->~MaybeT();
    std::construct_at(addr, obj);
}

#include <functional>

constexpr int test()
{
    int a = -1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 5;
    auto arr = FlexArray<std::reference_wrapper<int>>::newArr(3);
    arr.push_back(std::ref(a));
    arr.push_back(std::ref(b));
    arr.push_back(std::ref(c));
    arr.get(1).get() = 7;
    auto sum = arr.get(0) + b + arr.get(2);
    arr.deleteArr();
    return sum;
}

static_assert(test() == 11);
```

[See it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzACcpAAOqAqETgwe3r56KWmOAkEh4SxRMQm2mPYFDEIETMQEWT5%2BXJXVGXUNBEVhkdFxiQr1jc05bcPdvSVlgwCUtqhexMjsHOaxwcjeWADUJrFubCwkAJ4H2CYaAIIbWzuY%2B4eiCkqNF1e3NwSYLEkGPyebgIpySjFYjwAKh8btsmK9dgAxeiqa7EYhMc43EwAdisNySXgitDwyBAn12lKRKLRGNOEDQDGG1MwqPRmPMADY5k8ACK7LD0H4HfHXKkstl0rm7VBgjFEYgHXkMgTM5Gs2kcszcvkCqqYYWxUUUqmTRzIXaM4aspLECWa067EIAd1pEC8TLwwBC6F2wQIlqYSSYyEIpzmIpNlKtP1Utt2ADdUHhfYKDZg3RGjVHLarY/GPWlvZhff7dmkAF6YCA8mORm7imM2u2Fr0%2Bv2CQPB0Mgmu5pkEetiqlNuN26Ha3bAA3uz3F0ud4JYVRZ0WNvPNxPJ32EhQIAD6ERDAGsIJD%2B8NpagItpV59Pra8AmmD9yQ3TQRiF4HLsABKYJgsDtXE13FKlW3nDsA0rTAhzA8C53bMtRG7MM4KpXFeXQykzVJC98ztJgvCIXZIX3OV9wYDBHiVHMIBg1AqDPHkDjccs8CrRiIH/QDojmFjYkRdjOKYnigLmAB6BimMhHkQF2Lg5Gw3YPQyXYAFlMSic8QJzcUIPbZAEAaAUfBYc5s3feDz2vbQhz0kcNzHDStMwSE%2B10nEsKssCbRJHt8M3TTTm0lUB1I6UFBWOSZRvejov2PFMIc6MnPjAA/YLQpYpKvJzZLLOHSlVIEXY5ES0D4LE6JdgQAD0GU8UsrcgUXyYEwAFYLDIiiqKwTqsMK%2BDUoHTc5D7eT0Dazz%2BRmlLAuc9Lxpyqw8p8grjR8uQAConWohRlL80lCAW%2BN1UlTEIB2p0Yr6zAFAgBgVuS7E8sKz4fj%2BAEaMOEEwWYNgItiS5YTSu1zodVjoWB%2B12QstxoewEAQBdN0DJLKCuxDMMI1eyrdiIkiXUo/bdRdMrOosLh9ksXYGSDbGQRpiw6Z66ISawABaLh%2BIktniA52COsG/Hibug6uo0AaADo6sA3UQI0UgsZ7c43vx4gDWWBhYalPExf2jb7zWr5rk%2B/4Xx%2B4FQXBQHEc%2BUd4yTFNdY5Q5EeRtMfkzY38fRhcAzwXUYJrZTnQQOhHggPBOc556fPFacCGjuZpfS9y73Wk3xS9oWrGFvasAOoaqXFsmvFoWgkk/eyTY%2B34LcBVi/ttqEYWuR2W0QjGywhuGoYuZGQ9rPNfZzTWCG1wv7spqXhdl%2BrpZg2vvNN83vqBFuAbb4GHbBlTu4D134Y9lAGdVvs6zx8eteIHXxdnmW5fQaWUMZizjTr74G435ube3oGIMO77wnJyY%2BA9gbIyTrOIsSFFwMGXLjW4SUfITyng/Lq1NrAdmXLsCSpFyLszujLKa9RKZLlZDTDqBDerURlrZFe95v5fUtpvf%2BEJAF71Gs5Z2vo%2B5SndoPEAu4DxHmQKeGMEVJy2SQbpHy8I3jJ2HkCFWYYayZyKgTYiqAcGUKVNPCWFg568gXoBJeHFYKWGsMpZq55tqAXQMBWI/IMFU2Zro1QeCaFELofPUhTB3HRwQXosw1D%2BaCw0eKBxxBOYXEyq5DOylhjoGRjGL8Dh9wvggNE5WMjGHYmxGYTYDBtheD2KxKgHoHAZDEO3Lh1pnJlh%2BMMUO18fJlgCfo7mykywRF1GYHpnYLT6I6spQmOiGhOP5Pwt2bhknI01lQaIjBVj7mdBiJIcpWL%2Bg%2BJAlGmBXToggLESJVJJnSxEYeE89ECApJAIs7J/ExnoguV4PcVzxE3LuQ8iITyS6UnOZcsRp55n3MwExZAfz8bnOgTzaW0CBL8hxGM7R5YfC6hhTODQLFaZ9OwZi5OZhTkApebnH2/zdhoLvmilg%2BTTa4WQJk140Rk7NOToi/RXAeZDg4AsWgnAOq8D8BwLQpBUCcDcNY2mCglgrBokUngpACCaF5QsY8IAOqcmlpyMwkguAdQABycniJySQZhzWav0JwSQQqVVis4LwBQIAlbKpFby0gcBYBIEZPwYgLBDCrHIJQNAfxI7ECdbAENSQw0AEkUlwiMPuT8HpjxiurhkJ1HBObJKVKYKxlgzAaF2JzAA6mIWgxaS2sk/AEzmYIpqCFJO6lUob6DEDjSAYAChmBJD3KgAgaaaiZuzbc3NUqLCFsreWyt1aMTFvrYYc0zao2xpSQmZAmz9wJi4PEfc31hj7lUKawdGbOBSVuSgcdk6JIlskHguULA8CvCfJgTmqrSAlkICQFMegDBGA7Xmqwlh9B4AiBG9RVqOCCtIMK0V4qOAeAYL6/1JTHgADU8AHJqhAXAX7gIKp5LECSXBRWuq0PxUg6rJCxGlrEHEhq9WxA0LEDqOI2OckgzamDdr4OOudUqlVFH%2BUcDMLat19qOC8DI%2B%2BhM0Q0jOEkEAA).

Comment: This is awesome! If you do this minor change, it works with older versions of clang too (pre trunk) https://godbolt.org/z/PGrEoeobb

Comment: One thing to note is that this potentially wastes a lot of memory https://godbolt.org/z/rTehrv9ME

Comment: Hmm, yes. That could be improved some by putting the size and capacity in separate "nodes", but it will still act as though `T` has alignment at least `sizeof(size)`. In practice, probably not a lot of useful types have the combinations of size and alignment which would cause a lot of waste?

Comment: Or maybe with appropriate partial specializations, it could handle this sort of case by making the header a sequence of bytes, and manually doing arithmetic to convert between byte values and size/capacity values.